# "Error: type property can't be changed". Getting error while using ngTagInput library (AngularJs)

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I am getting an strange error while using ngTagInput library:

> Error: type property can't be changed.

Here is the screenshot of that error - [Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjQed.jpg).

HTML Code -

```
<html ng-app="project">
 <head>
  <link href="/css/ng-tags-input.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/css/ng-tags-input.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript"  src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js'></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='/js/angular.min.js'></script>  
  <script src="/js/ng-tags-input.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<form ng-controller="MainCtrl" role="form">
 <div class="col-md-12 topM10px">
    <tags-input ng-model="formInfo.tags" placeholder="Add a keyword"></tags-input>        
 </div> 

 <div class="col-md-12 topM10px">
    <div ng-click="submitidea()" class="col-md-3 submitbtn">Submit</div>      
 </div> 

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller code (app.js)-

```
var app = angular.module('project', ['ngTagsInput']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   $scope.formInfo = {};
   $scope.tags = [
     { text: 'Tag1' },
     { text: 'Tag2' },
     { text: 'Tag3' }
   ];
$scope.submitidea = function(){
    console.log($scope.formInfo);     
 }
});
```

Please someone help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add your controller code?

Comment: Updated with controller code @DanielNalbach

Comment: Is this all of your code? Can you post the full html? I was successful in setting up a fiddle with ng-input-tags and want to see if there is something else in your code that could be an issue.

Comment: If you comment out jquery and bootstrap dependencies, does that make the error go away?

Comment: Hey daniel, I have updated the code @DanielNalbach

Comment: yes, then there is no error if I comment out those two

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: AngularJS v1.5.0-rc.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to have a conflict between one of more of your libraries. This can probably be resolved by isolating which library is causing the issue (when commented out, the error goes away), and then trying different versions of that library and/or Angular.

I did a fiddle that uses the same version of Bootstrap and jQuery that you are, but is using Angular 1.4.8 instead of 1.5, so I believe the conflict is between jQuery 1.8.1 and Angular v1.5.0-rc.0 since the fiddle works without any errors. Recommend dropping your Angular version down to 1.4.8 and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: thanks.. that was jquery version issue.. I just updated to 1.9.1 and it worked !!.. you saved my time

Comment: Excellent, and thank you for posting the update on which version resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add library angular first

For example:

Comment: I think there is sth missing in your answer. please review it.

Comment: Thanks @Diana for your time. But this issue is resolved earlier. :)